# Secure phone against a custom firmware being flashed remotely

Tags: security, rom-flashing

[image: app usage which shows apps have been running since 1969 from star code menu]

My phone restarted extra long for no reason and now the firmware is different. It shows up as generic android device not moto g pure. Can I encrypt the hardware to prevent this in the future?

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally installed an GSI image?

Comment: The image I posted comes from the star code menu. I think the girl who had my phone took a screenshot and when I got home someone ran possibly remote fastboot. I'm not sure but it happened to 2 other phones too. I have not flashed anything since the days of snow breeze redsnow and ultra snow and greenpoison and that was all ipod touch

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell without knowing how this happened, so if you had for example some kind of virus, removing that would solve this.

If you haven't rooted your phone, secure boot should prevent anything like this though, have you rooted yours?

Unless this is an actual update from Motorola that auto installed.

TLDR you need to work out what caused it before you can start to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was a deliberate question or you are just confused on what you did.

Entering `*#*#4636#*#*` in the Phone app brings you to this Testing page where you can check all sorts of info regarding your phone like Wifi, NFC, Usage, Phone info, etc.

> Here are some other codes you can try
>
> 1. Phone information
>    *#*#4636#*#*
> 2. IMEI Info
>    *#06#
> 3. Calendar
>    *#*#225#*#*
> 4. FCM Diagnostics
>    *#*#426#*#*
> 5. Engineering Mode
>    *#*#2486#*#*
> 6. Regulatory information
>    *#07#

[Source](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/motorola/motorola-moto-g8-plus/codes/)